# Find the largest integer whose square is not greater than N in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Find the largest integer whose square is not greater than N.

For example:

- Input 1: isqrt(8,R) => Output: R = 2, because 2^2 = 4 <= 8.
- Input 2: isqrt(9,R) => Output: R = 3, because 3^2 = 9 <= 9.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

```
?- Limit = 10, 
   forall( ( between(0,Limit,X), 
             X**2 < Limit
           ), 
           writeln(X)).
0
1
2
3
```